# how to get quote item of the current quote?

Tags: magento2, quoteitem

how to get quote item of the current quote? i have already get the quote i'll share some code .

```
$quote = $this->quoteFactory->create()->load(13);
//echo "<pre>";print_r($collection->getData());
$shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();

//form data
$firstname = $quote->getCustomerFirstname();
$lastname = $quote->getCustomerLastname();
$mail = $quote->getcustomer_email();
//shipping Address
$city = $shippingAddress->getCity();
$address1 = $shippingAddress->getStreet(1); // Get the first line of the street address
$address2 = $shippingAddress->getStreet(1);
//$address2 = $shippingAddress->getAddress2(); // Region code
//$postcode = $shippingAddress->getPostcode();
//$country = $shippingAddress->getCountry();
$phone = $shippingAddress->getTelephone();
$state = $shippingAddress->getRegion();
$zip= $shippingAddress->getPostcode();
```

here i get the quote now i also want to get the quote item

Answer (score 0):

To get the quote item of the current quote you can use the Here's how you can do it

```
$quoteId = 13; // Your quote ID
$quote = $this->quoteFactory->create()->load($quoteId);

    // Check if the quote is loaded successfully
    if ($quote->getId()) {
        // Get the items of the quote
        // Depending on the use case, you can use \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote::getAllItems or \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote::getAllVisibleItems
        $items = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
    
        // Loop through the items to perform your operations
        foreach ($items as $item) {
             // Access individual item data
             $itemId = $item->getId();
             $productName = $item->getName();
        }
    } else {
           // Quote with the specified ID not found
           echo "Quote not found!";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code.

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend'); // or 'adminhtml' if you're running the code in the admin area

// Get the current quote
$quote = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session')->getQuote();

// Get quote items
$items = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();

// Loop through each item
foreach ($items as $item) {
    // Get item details
    $itemId = $item->getId();
    $productName = $item->getName();
    $productPrice = $item->getPrice();
    // Additional item details can be obtained using other methods of $item object
    
    // Do something with the item details
    echo "Item ID: $itemId, Product Name: $productName, Price: $productPrice <br>";
}
```

**`THANKS.`**